# A nice proof that completely bounded (cb) norm of transpose map on $ M_n $ is n

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, operator-norms

In my research of operator algebras and their connection with machine learning I of course use the well know result:

> For the map $ tr:M_n \to M_n $ denoting the transpose map of matrices (meaning that $ tr(A)=A^{tr} $ we know for the completely bounded norm (cb-norm) that $ ||tr||_{cb}=n $

I keep using this result freely but to be honest it had just occurred to me that I know not a proof of this nor do I have a reference for the proof or an idea for proving it that would actually work, could operator algebraists out there please help in providing a proof or a reference to a nice (or any...) functioning proof of this useful fact?

Comment: Do people actually use $\textrm{tr}$ to denote the transpose map? that conflicts with the matrix trace...

Comment: This is almost surely in Pisier's book, or the book of Effros and Ruan, or Paulsen's book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I literally just googled "cb norm of transpose" and got a link to [this math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1320435/calculating-norms-for-the-transpose) which links to a proof.

Edit: the answer which contained the link disappeared, so I used Google magic again and found [Tomiyama's original paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2045453?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) with this calculation.

Comment: Author deleted his answer. It is better to give a link to the Ruan's book 'Operator spaces'